# Is the below xml file right?

Tags: android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout, android-cardview

Is the below xml file right? I am trying to display information that I have fetched from sqlite in recycler view.

Is the below xml file right? I am trying to display information that I have fetched from sqlite in recycler view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="3dp"
                android:layout_height="23dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/semester"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.15"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView32"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SGPA"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.7" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView33"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Percentage"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.70" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView32"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.08"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView32"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView32"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textVw"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView33"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.08"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView33"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView33" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/scheme1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.95" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btndelete1"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.96"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.05"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is what I want:

[image]

And this is what I am getting:

[image]

I don't know why. Can someone help me out?

Also, if needed, this is where I am calling the recycler view:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

        <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android

.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".drawernav.bottom_navi.recycler_view.sgpa_frag">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rc1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/else2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="It's a bit lonely here..."
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean? "xml is right?"

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin I have attached two pictures which show what is expected and what is actually happening. I tried to solve this and could not. So I just used linear layout instead of constraint layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this layout:

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btndelete1"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btndelete1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/semester"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.15"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView32"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SGPA"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.7"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView33"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Percentage"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView32"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btndelete1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/semester"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView32"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.70"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.18" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView32"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/semester"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.08"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/semester"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView32"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textVw"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView33"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btndelete1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.08"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView33"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView33" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scheme1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btndelete1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btndelete1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btndelete1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.96"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.05"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.1"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have used those attributes to make your layout responsive:

```
app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" 
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
```

In addition, I added [Guideline](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html)

**And it will look like this:**

[image]

Comment: What exactly not working, what view is not responsive?

Comment: The width of the card view is not matching the parent. It is stuck to the left side.